# What is the base of the `log` in tf-idf?

Tags: tf-idf

I have seen [the wikipedia's document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Definition). For idf in this document, log10 is used.

I have seen other examples of idf, using log base of e or ln.

What is the difference? Is there any significant difference or a correct alternative?

Comment: They only differ by a [multiplicative constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base). Since this is the same for all terms, the choice doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you @user20160